# Probability distribution for a Bayesian Update

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, bayesian-probability

I am struggling with a process like this:
$$X_t=\begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha\omega_t}{\alpha\omega_t+\beta(1-\omega_t)} & \text{with prob } p\\
\frac{(1-\alpha)\omega_t}{(1-\alpha)\omega_t+(1-\beta)(1-\omega_t)} & \text{with prob } 1-p
\end{cases}$$ where $\alpha\in(0,0.5)$ and $\beta\in(0.5,1)$.
Now introduce the process (which is a Bayesian update)
$$
\omega_{t+1}=k+hX_t
$$ where $h,k\in[0,1]$
Thus, $X_t$ is a simple Bernoulli trial, but it assumes different values at any time step $t$, since it depends on $\omega_t$.
My question is then: Is it possible to compute the distribution of $\omega$? I made some numerical simulations: distribution is not always the same and it changes depending on parameters $\alpha, \beta, h, k$.
Following I attach two simulations-example of the density of $\omega$ with different combinations of parameters (sorry if I am rude and i didn't rename axis label and title :D).

Many thanks
[image]

[image]

Comment: This question might better fit in the stats forum https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: A close relative to the density of $\omega_t$ is finding the limiting/stationary distribution as $t$ grows. If the coin flips are iid, the process $\omega_t$ is Markov since it only depends on the previous step. So there is some hope for finding transition density Matrix (if we restrict to discrete times) and then stationary distribution.

Comment: this is quite a complicated definition also because if the jump step k is too large, then $\omega_t$ quickly heads to $\frac{\beta}{\beta-\alpha}$ and thus the Xt diverges. This boundary effect makes it a bit hard to study.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that $\omega$ lies between 0 and 1, so X cannot diverge.